# Send mail with Iron IO Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I use command:

```
php artisan queue:subscribe laravel http://your-site-url/queue/push
```

and get error:

[Http_Exception] 
 http error: 0 | SSL certificate problem. verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:

error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed.
 failed
queue:subscribe [--type[="... "]] queue url

I was sign up at iron.io and add project_id, token and default key driver to iron in app/config/queue.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a IronIO problem, to circumvent it on Laravel you can add this to your `app/start/global.php` file:

```
Queue::connection()->getIron()->ssl_verifypeer = false;
```

Look at the vendor\iron-io\iron_mq readme:

```
Troubleshooting

http error: 0

If you see  `Uncaught exception 'Http_Exception' with message 'http error: 0 | '`
it most likely caused by misconfigured cURL https sertificates.
There are two ways to fix this error:

1. Disable SSL sertificate verification - add this line after IronMQ initialization: `$ironmq->ssl_verifypeer = false;`
2. Switch to http protocol - add this to configuration options: `protocol = http` and `port = 80`
```

Also, you can just manually subscribe to your url directly in the IronMQ web admin page:

```
1. Go to https://hud.iron.io/dashboard

2. On your projects, click in tue MQ button of your project

3. Select the "Queues" tab

4. Click on your queue name, this must be the same you subscribed to using the command "artisan queue:subscribe"

5. In the "PUSH INFORMATION" box, check if your queue push type is set to "multicast".

6. Add a your url in the "SUBSCRIBERS" box.
```

Comment: 1. Disable SSL sertificate verification - add this line after IronMQ initialization: `$ironmq->ssl_verifypeer = false;` Where IronMQ initialization? 2. Switch to http protocol - add this to configuration options: `protocol = http` and `port = 80`. Mean: add `protocol = http` and `port = 80` into iron_mq/sample_config.ini?

Comment: I took those lines from IronMQ, not Laravel, those were not supposed to be steps to fix your problem, but I just edited to add a Laravel way to disable IronMQ SSL. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I was add line Queue::connection()->getIron()->ssl_verifypeer = false; into bottom file app/start/global.php and the problem is resolved. my app in localhost and i use host by ngrok. Thank's.

Comment: Cool! I'm glad it worked. So I just edited the answer to make it a little more objective for Laravel users.